# Alternativa para IF e Else num problema específico

Tags: c#

**PROBLEMA**

Tenho armazenado no banco, cinco tipos de conjuntos de dados, diferentes entre si. Imagine, para exemplificar, que esse conjunto de dados são detalhes de cinco frutas diferentes, por exemplo, banana, maça, laranja, uva e pera, por exemplo. A estrutura de dados é diferente para cada uma das frutas, nesse exemplo hipotético.

Na aplicação, o usuário entra como o termo de pesquisa apropriado e tem como retorno os detalhes de todas as cinco frutas; Ou, apenas de uma; Ou, duas; Ou, três; Ou quatro; ou nenhuma. Por exemplo, se o usuário entrar como o termo "casca dura" vai coincidir com característica presente nas cinco frutas.

Eu utilizo uma variável de controle para cada resultado. Cada variável pode conter "registro" ou não conter nenhum "registro". Assim, como são cinco variáveis, eu tenho trinta e duas possibilidades para verificar.

Eu utilizo o ListView para exibir os dados na aplicação, e para melhorar a experiência do usuário, defini um controle para cada fruta, pois a estrutura dos dados das tabelas são diferentes para cada fruta.

Eu utilizo If e Else como solução, e funciona.

**Eu tenho como objetivo solucionar esse problema utilizando uma abordagem diferente no c#, sem que eu precise modificar a estrutura no banco, visto que são milhares de registros já consolidados.**

Um recorte de como estou fazendo:

```
//Situação 1 - V V V V V

 if (detalhes1 != 0 && detalhes2 == 0 && detalhes3 == 0 && detalhes4 == 0 && 
 detalhes5 == 0) 

 {

 ....
 .
 .

  ListViewDetalhes1.DataSource = detalhes1Colecao;                                 
  ListViewDetalhes1.DataBind();

  }
```

e assim vou mapeando cada possibilidade ate "fechar" as trinta e duas.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, detalhes1 2 e 3 são os detalhes da fruta certo? Onde esta a variável termo pesquisado em questão, onde você faz a comparação desse termo pesquisado?

Comment: Eu acho que poderia ser interessante você aplicar *Azure Machine Learning* nisto, para não ter que ficar usando IF.  https://www.bing.com/search?q=azure+machine+learning

Comment: @AlberttSantos na camada de negócios eu tenho um método onde passo a string que o usuário insere para pesquisar. Por exemplo: detalhes1Colecao = detalhes1Negocios.ConsultaTodas(termopesquisado); Eu faço isso com todas as 5 variáveis, pois o modelo de dados é diferente nas tabelas. Após, pego o resultado de cada variável...

Comment: É impressão minha ou você esta atribuindo uma responsabilidade para a aplicação que na verdade seria do banco de dados? Pois se trás os dados, por quê "filtra" novamente os dados recebidos?

Comment: É necessário atender ao critério pesquisado, e exibir o resultado apropriado.

Comment: Mostre a estrutura do banco por favor, e alguns dados de exemplo

Answer (score 3):

Por que você não usa um conjunto de "flags" booleanos para cada uma das suas trinta e duas variáveis e depois submete a um "SWITCH", seria algo +/- assim (requer ajustes):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool[] array = new bool[32];
        int[] detalhes = new int[32];
        string[] frutas = new string[5];
        frutas[0] = "banana";
        frutas[1] = "maçã";
        frutas[2] = "laranja";
        frutas[3] = "uva";
        frutas[4] = "pera";


        for (int i = 0; i < frutas.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < detalhes.Length; y++)
            {
                array[i] = false;

                switch (detalhes[i])
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            array[i] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```